# display portfolio items in desc order in portfolio plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, portfolio

I am using this shortcode to display portfolio items, it is displaying items in ascending order. But I want to display items in desc order. Here are some options of sorting items in admin side, but these are not according to my requirements. I want to set it manually.

I am using this shortcode `[af-portfolio]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try using 
[af-portfolio order="desc"]
```

Comment: Then I will suggest you try to write your own query, rather than relying on the shortcode and fetch the contents the way you are looking for